# Gmail Filter - Give Label To A List Of Incoming And Outgoing Emails Containing Email Address From A Certain List Of Email Addresses

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I've a list of email addresses (let's give it a name `Cool Email Addresses` for understanding purpose)

```
Email A
Email B
Email C
```

The emails I've sent and received should be given a label `Label XYZ` if the email sent or received contains one or more than one email addresses from the list `Cool Email Addresses`.

How can I create a filter like this?

Comment: Closely related: [How to add filter and label to group in gmail contacts?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/20020)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new filter in Gmail and put this query in the "Has the words" field:

```
(to:(emailA@example.com OR emailB@example.com OR emailC@example.com)) 
OR (from:(emailA@example.com OR emailB@example.com OR emailC@example.com))
```